# Send message to a client from server asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a got a portal, where users login in post a job. I then store that job in the database and then I have a console application running every X minutes to look for new jobs and process the job. all working fine.

My problem is, I  can't figure out how to tell the user that their job is completed if user is online. I have had a look at snackbar. but I don't understand how i can be used for specific clients only i.e only one who have submitted the job request and is completed.

1. I can write the job done status to a file with user user IP address. if that helps.
2. If the The user is still online then display the message. There is a possibility that the user submit a job and close the browser.
3. The user can come back after some time and the result file will be available to view, this bit is working.
4. The job finish time is not known.

I have been looking for the past week but I can't figure out how to do this. That I why I have asked this question.

Comment: [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) or [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) would seem to be ideal for this

Comment: Don't rely strictly on user IP. That can change and multiple users can also have same IP

Comment: The login and results are based on IP.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you please write a very basic example in .net